# How to guarantee message order when multiple instances update elasticsearch?

Tags: python, multithreading, elasticsearch, design-patterns, apache-kafka

Lets say I have a Queue listening to `Kafka` containing realtime messages.

I also have a "worker" that get the message from the Queue and performs updates on `Elasticsearch`. When I scale my project by adding more "worker" instances, how can I maintain the order of the messages?

How can I avoid one "worker" instance get the later message from the queue but finish update to `Elasticsearch` earlier?

Comment: Leverage Kafka partitioning and make sure related messages go to the same partition since only one worker can process a partition.

Comment: But all my messages go to the queue. "worker" listens to the queue, not Kafka. Queue is like the middle buffer between kafka and Elasticsearch

Comment: why do you have a queue if you already have Kafka?

Comment: My bad. between Kafka and "my queue", I have a, lets say "filter". The purpose of "filter" is to eliminate the unwanted messages before doing the actual calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the choice you have to make between parallel processing and sequencing.

you must have single partition for the topic to maintain the order of data. So you can have a max of 1 task in worker , additional task will be unassigned.